# How to Write Other Custom Export Function Along with socket.io in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to emit an event after notification save:

```
'saveNotification' : function saveNotification(to_id, from_id, message,type, post_id, cb){

    var notification = new Notification({
        to_id : to_id,
        from_id : from_id,
    });
    notification.save(function(err , notification){

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return cb(false);      
        } else {

           // I want to emit an event here
             socket.emit()

        }
    });
},`
```

How can I do it io from app.js like

```
require('./controller/socket')(io);
```

So how can I do this both save notification which will be called from different routes after that I want to emit, so how I can include socket.io object while sending notification?

Comment: Are you using Express?

Comment: yes, i am using expresss

Comment: You can use module.exports and can get **io** in controller/socket. like this `module.exports = function (io) { // you can emit an event here }`